# Is it possible to reset authorizationStatus of CLLocationManager in macOS?

Tags: macos, testing, core-location

On macOS, is there a way to reset the `authorizationStatus` of the `CLLocationManager` back to  `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` (or `.notDetermined` in Swift)? Disabling the location permission for the app in System Settings only sets it to `kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied` (`.denied`) which is not the same thing. Only when not determined, calling `requestAlwaysAuthorization` has an effect, in all other cases this method has no effect on macOS (that's also how it is documented). But currently I can do that once on a development system and then never again. Even if I clear the Xcode build directory, the app will vanish from System Settings but the moment I re-build it, it's there before even starting it with the last status set, so I cannot re-test prompting the user for access.

Comment: I think it's in `/var/db/locationd/clients.plist`, you can edit with `sudo`

Answer (score 1):

The [comment from TheNextman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78188599/is-it-possible-to-reset-authorizationstatus-of-cllocationmanager-in-macos?noredirect=1#comment137844875_78188599) pointed me into the right direction. Location permissions are indeed stored in `/var/db/locationd/clients.plist`. To edit this file, you must be root; actually you already must be root to view the file or enter its directory. But you also must kill `locationd` otherwise your edit has no effect. Here is a step by step guide:

1. Open Terminal
2. Become root: `sudo su -`
3. Go to the directory: `cd /var/db/locationd`
4. Find the identifier of your app: `plutil -p cilents.plist`. The identfier will be something like `A436F23B-8069-4F67-B935-1DF9FE5F5903:icom.apple.iCal:`
5. Delete app entry:

   ```
   defaults delete `pwd`/clients.plist A436F23B-8069-4F67-B935-1DF9FE5F5903:icom.apple.iCal:
   ```

   (`defaults` will only work here with absolute path, hence the `` `pwd`/ ``)
6. Force `locationd` to restart: `killall locationd`

After those steps the status is back to `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` (`.notDetermined`).

Comment: And note that _most_ privacy permissions are stored in the tcc database, and can be reset with `tccutil`. Location seems to be an outlier here.

Comment: @TheNextman Yes, I checked `tccutil` but it seems that is doesn't know anything of location services. The man page lists no services to begin with but the following list is known: https://recoursive.com/2020/03/03/reset_macos_privacy_permissions  I tried `tccutil reset All` but that did not reset the location status, that's why I asked the question on SO.